# If $y=e^{a\tan^{-1} x},$ then prove that:

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=e^{a\tan^{-1} x}$, then prove that:
$$(1+x^2).y_{n+2}+(2nx+2x-a).y_{n+1}+n(n+1).y_n=0$$

My Attempt:
$$y=e^{a\tan^{-1} x}$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, 
$$y_{1}=a.e^{a\tan^{-1} x}.\dfrac {1}{1+x^2}$$
$$(1+x^2)y_{1}=a.e^{a\tan^{-1} x}$$
Again, differentiating both sides with respect to $x$,
$$(1+x^2)y_2+y_1.2x=a.a.e^{a\tan^{-1} x} \dfrac {1}{1+x^2}$$
$$(1+x^2)^2.y_2+2x(1+x^2)y_1-a^2y=0$$

Comment: What is $y_n$? The $n$-th derivative?

Comment: Typically, $y'$, $y''$, $y'''$, $y^{(4)}$, etc. are used to represent the derivative functions.

Comment: induction can work here

Answer (score 3):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y&=&a e^{ \tan^{-1}(x) } \\
y' &=& \frac{a e^{ \tan^{-1}(x) }}{1+x^2}  \implies (1+x^2)y'=ay \\
(1+x^2)y''&+&(2x-a)y' =0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus the base case is proved.

We continue inductively

Assume
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x^2)y^{(n+1)}+(2nx-a)y^{(n)}+(n-1)ny^{(n-1)} =0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Differentiating gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x^2)y^{(n+2)}+(2x+ 2nx-a)y^{(n+1)}+((n-1)n+2n)y^{(n)} =0 \\ 
(1+x^2)y^{(n+2)}+( 2(n+1)x-a)y^{(n+1)}+(n(n+1))y^{(n)} =0 \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
as required.

Comment: can we use $n-1$ insted of $n$? that will give proper solution